# Receiving "This week's top job matches" mail although no alert is defined

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I am currently receiving the "This week's top job matches", and I have no idea how I can disable this. I have no alert defined in the "Job Alerts" tab in my settings, all the emails are currently disabled in the mail preferences, and I have no subscriptions whatsoever.

When I click on "Unsubscribe from this email" it just sends me back to job alerts and I see no alert defined there.

How do I disable this email?

Also I made sure that the box "Not interested in jobs" is checked in my profile.

Comment: I see that you are effectively opted out of the email matches, and there's no reason for you to receive them. I'll take a look into this tomorrow (if nobody else beats me to it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, mystery solved :)

You had 2 accounts. On one, you were subscribed to job matches, on the other one you weren't. They were merged on StackOverflow, but that merge didn't complete on jobs, so you ended up having two accounts... and it was impossible for you to manage the orphan one.

I've manually merged them and verified that you're effectively opted out.

Once you choose "Not interested in jobs" you should receive exactly 0 emails from us (unless *you* create an alert or apply to a job or send a message to an employer). Anything else is a bug.

Thanks for the report!

Comment: Thank you for the quick solve !